# JavaScript and browser tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this isn't possible but I'll ask anyway. What I want to be able to do is detect if a website is open in another tab, then using JavaScript, open up the same website but with a different query string in that same tab

The only way I can think of doing it is if they open the tab on our website first with a name, then next time they click on to the other website, using the same name it should open in the same tab, this isn't preferable as most users will have opened up the other website either by typing it in or from a bookmark

Answer (score 0):

You may play around with 2 things:

- localStorage
- window.name

The approach could be following: every time your site is open, you store window.name to the local storage. If name is not present, you generate one.

Every time on start-up you check if there is a name saved in local storage, if it is, then you remove the name from the storage, and reload your website like this:

```
window.open(url,"name");
```

That should load the page into the open tab, or open new tab with that name.

One problem, however, is that a new window, that was openning your request is remaining in there, cause script cannot close windows that were not open by it.